# How do I get Ruby Regex to match everything the way I need it to?

Tags: ruby, regex, digits

Sorry, I couldn't think of a better title, because the issue is much more complicated than what can go in that little box. Call me an idiot, but I couldn't think of a simple way to sum this up.

I am working on a plugin for a bot, it's a weather plugin, and I want it to be very intuitive and easy to use for the users (as most programmers do). Here is my regex and a snippet of the code

`match /forecast (\d+ )?(.+)/i, method: :checkForecast`

```
  def checkForecast(m, time=0, location)
    return if check_ignore(m.user)

    formattedLocation = location.gsub! /\s/, '+'
    coordinates       = geoLookup(formattedLocation)
    return m.reply "No results found for #{location}." if coordinates.nil?

    address = findAddress(formattedLocation)

    timeframe = time.to_i

    data    = fetchForecast(m, coordinates, address, timeframe, true)
    return m.reply 'Uh oh, there was a problem fetching the specified forecast. Please try again later. :(' if data.nil?

    m.reply(data)

    alert = checkAlert(formattedLocation, address, true)
    return m.user.notice "You have no alerts." if alert.nil?

    m.user.notice(alert)
  end
```

So, right now the following match the regex like I need it to:

"forecast 15 Juneau, Alaska" This will go to the 15th spot in the array after looking up Juno, Alaska and return the needed results

"forecast Juneau, Alaska" This will default to the 0 spot in the array and return the nearest forecast for Juno, Alaska

Now if I type these, it either doesn't match at all, or thinks it's part of the location:

"forecast 99801" Throws an exception saying that [] is an undefined method.

"forecast 10 99801" With this one it thinks I'm asking for #10 Juneau, Alaska, because it's including it in the last group.

"forecast 12 1201 First st. Juneau, Alaska" Thinks that it's all part of the second group again.

Basically, I need the regex to be constructed so it does everything I'd like it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you expect here :)  So let me just start by explaining why your examples aren't behaving as you want:

> "forecast 99801" Throws an exception saying that [] is an undefined method.

Your first group includes a trailing space, and so doesn't match, so the `"99801"` is matched by the `.+` and therefore is passed as the `location` argument to your `checkForecast` method.

For some reason you used `gsub!` which if it doesn't match returns `nil`, and because there's no whitespace in `"99801"` then `formattedLocation` is set to `nil` and I'm guessing that your `geoLookup` method expects it to be something which `[]` can be called on.

> "forecast 10 99801" With this one it thinks I'm asking for #10 Juneau, Alaska, because it's including it in the last group.

`"10 "` is the first group so will be treated the same as `15` in your working example, but the `"99801"` will have the same problems as above.

> "forecast 12 1201 First st. Juneau, Alaska" Thinks that it's all part of the second group again.

The first group will be `"12 "` which will mean `timeframe` will be `12` and the rest of the string will be `location` and will become: `"1201+First+st.+Juneau,+Alaska"` in `formattedLocation`

---

So, maybe that helps, just to have a walkthrough. If not then you really need to explain what you're after here.

Comment: It's really hard to explain in words exactly what I want. I want the end user to be able to type any logical trigger and get a good response. Essentially, I want the regex to work intuitively with the end user. I want someone to be able to type `forecast 99801` and have the script default to 0 in the array like it should, and then deliver the weather result. I want it to return with the specified number in the array if someone were to type `forecast 12 99801`, like that

Comment: ...but what is that "99801" value, is that a zipcode that is always going to by 5 integers? These are the sorts of things you need to explain and specify in order to write a working regex.

Comment: Yeah, it would be a zipcode that always has 5 integers.